# destroy fragment completely Android

Tags: android-fragments

i have an activity and i want to change fragments depending on the orientation of the device. so here is my code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

 if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.calendrier_calendrierhebdomadaire) != null){
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.calendrier_calendrierhebdomadaire);
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1){       
    ft.add(R.id.calendrier_planifications, new Planifications());
}

else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2){

    ft.add(R.id.calendrier_planifications, new Planifications());
    ft.add(R.id.calendrier_calendrierhebdomadaire, new Test());  

}

ft.commit();
```

I am using two different layout files : layout/calendrier.xml containing two LinearLayouts, layout-port/calendrier.xml containing 1 LinearLayout

the problem is when i start my application in the landscape mode (orientation == 2) and switch it to the portrait mode (orientation == 1), i still have methods of my fragment Test executed.

How to completely remove the Test Fragment ?

Comment: could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have created two transactions, but only committed the second one. Try removing this line:

```
ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: i tried what you said, it didn't work
i tried to commit and create a new one, it didn't work either